# How to Reload NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have NSCollectionView with full of items, have one scenario where after deletion of one item the collection view should be refresh and it should display update items.

I am able to delete item, but collection view is not refreshing,

googled a lot, but got nothing,

Comment: Thank you for asking. It helped me. Anoop Vaidya 's answer worked for me

Answer (score 7):

`NSCollectionView` is a subclass of `NSView`. And you must be  knowing MVC design pattern. View is intended only to show the data/values from the model.

In your case you must have some array. You need to update the array and set the content of NSCollectionView programmatically or using Cocoa Bindings.

```
- (void)setContent:(NSArray *)content;
```

Also you may need to refresh the view :

```
[yourCollectionView setNeedsDisplay:YES]
```

Answer (score 1):

Anoop's suggestion didn't work for, but following did, copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947063/equivalent-of-reloaddata-for-nscollectionview-to-redraw-item-views)

Turns out that the NSCollectionView item views can be refreshed by setting the ItemPrototype, e.g.,

```
ItemPrototype = new SomeViewController()
```

This causes all the existing views to be recreated.