# Equivalent of ReloadData for NSCollectionView to redraw item views

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscollectionview, xamarin.mac

I have a toggle to change the font attributes. In my NSOutlineView, I call ReloadData to have everything re-render. However, how can I force NSCollectionView to re-render. I tried

```
cvReader.NeedsLayout= true;
cvReader.Layout();

cvReader.NeedsDisplay = true;
cvReader.Display();
```

to no avail. Any hints much appreciated.

**Update.** I also tried

```
cvReader.NeedsDisplay = true;
cvReader.Window.ViewsNeedDisplay = true;
cvReader.Window.FlushWindowIfNeeded();
```

As well as assigning the content again. It feels like the item views are cached and not regenerated. Maybe there is a way to clear the item view cache?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that the NSCollectionView item views can be refreshed by setting the ItemPrototype, e.g.,

```
ItemPrototype = new SomeViewController()
```

This causes all the existing views to be recreated.